# In apache kafka, what's the producer configuration to control the max wait period before getting response from kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

In our application, for each request ( a REST endpoint POST call) which is causing a data update/insert into the DB and we have to publish/produce a message to Kafka for downstream systems to consume and do the further processing.

And, the SLA for most of the POST requests in our application is 5 sec and most of our POST calls are synchronous. That means, any processing wrapped up inside of a POST call should be finished within 5 sec to avoid the timeout issues.

With this setup, If a take scenario where I've wrapped up a DB call and a call to produce a message onto Kafka in a POST call , my question is, how can I control/set the max time that my kafka producer can wait before it gets a response from the broker?

Comment: Why you want to control the time max time as kafka is stream based until you read the stream the pointer does not move to next bit so you just keep reading write operation on different topics that should work hopefully !!!

Comment: I'm not sure if you are clear on my requirement. To re-iterate, from the producer end, I can't wait for more than 5 sec to kafka to respond when I produce/publish a message because the SLA for any request coming to my application is 5 sec and this  request can include a DB call in addition to the kafka call. Hope that clarifies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.timeout.ms` can be the config that you are looking for:

> **request.timeout.ms**: The configuration controls the maximum amount of time the client will wait for the response of a request. If the
>   response is not received before the timeout elapses the client will
>   resend the request if necessary or fail the request if retries are
>   exhausted. This should be larger than `replica.lag.time.max.ms` (a
>   broker configuration) to reduce the possibility of message duplication
>   due to unnecessary producer retries.

For version 2.1 or higher you should also consider to set `delivery.timeout.ms`.

> **delivery.timeout.ms**: An upper bound on the time to report success or failure after a call to send() returns. This limits the total time
>   that a record will be delayed prior to sending, the time to await
>   acknowledgement from the broker (if expected), and the time allowed
>   for retriable send failures. The producer may report failure to send a
>   record earlier than this config if either an unrecoverable error is
>   encountered, the retries have been exhausted, or the record is added
>   to a batch which reached an earlier delivery expiration deadline. The
>   value of this config should be greater than or equal to the sum of
>   `request.timeout.ms` and `linger.ms`.

For more information about `delivery.timeout.ms` you can check this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-91+Provide+Intuitive+User+Timeouts+in+The+Producer).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see this configuration and trying to understand what happens if linger.ms comes into play because of the load when records arrive faster than they can be sent out.

Comment: @Raj I don't know which version of Kafka you using but if it is 2.1 or higher. You should check delivery.timeout.ms producer config You should also check this link for more information: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-91+Provide+Intuitive+User+Timeouts+in+The+Producer

Comment: Got it, Thank you so much for the details.